# Prevent changing responsive webpage style after resizing(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was working on my website and I Was wondering how could I make it like Some other websites like Instagram after resizing.
let me explain a bit,
my website is responsive and as you already know it's style will change after you resize the width/height,
My question is, How could I prevent this,changing style instantly after resizing,and make it change **only after reloading the page**.

The best example is Instagram website (on desktop browser).
you can see that if you resize the page it won't change but right after reloading the page, it will change to the specified width and height.

I would be really happy if you could help me with this idea.
Regards
S.Rb

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What will be the advantage of this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirection you own page with a http get/post to check the viewport and administrate the .css that you link on the header. All the changes in css3 will be displayed without refreshing.